# REACT WEBPACK требует лоадер

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

Вебпак жалуется на react компонент требуя лоадер.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
ERROR in ./src/index.js 13:3
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (13:3)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| const root = createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
| root.render(
>    <App />
| );
```

Сталкивался ли кто с такой проблемой?

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего у Вас неправильно настроен проект и скрипт воспринимается как javascript, а не как react код. Попробуйте:

1. Попробовать переименовать `App.js` to `App.jsx`.
2. Обновить правило с  `test: /\.js$/`, на `test: /\.(js|jsx)$/`, в `webpack.config.js`
3. Проверить правильность названия файла `webpack.config.js` если имеет место неправильное именование файла (встречал иногда название `webpack-config.js` )
4. Если предыдущие шаги не помогут, приложите полное содержимое `index.js` и `webpack.config.js`, а также желательно файла `.babelrc` если таковой имеется.

Comment: Спасибо, исправил